# Is it possible to create a public web service in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: web-services, authentication, liferay, liferay-6

I've created some webservices using Liferay plugin system but I need some of them to be callable from outside (a mobile application) without any authentication. Is it possible ?

I've tried these settings:

auth.token.check.enabled=false

jsonws.web.service.public.methods=*

but without luck, using the jsonws web interface it still require a p_auth token and if I call them with a browser not logged into the portal I get:

"Authenticated access required"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`jsonws.service.public.methods` should be `json.service.public.methods`.

I have one portal where I use calendar's `getEvents` method with unauthorized access. The *portal-ext.properties* has the following line:

`json.service.public.methods=getEvents`

That's all. I don't remember it well, but I think the `*` wildcard did not work in 6.1.1. I had to write method name explicitly.